# Why is this program closing without writing the last print statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why is this program closing immediately after I press enter after I input my age? I thought that the last input() would make it wait for another input before closing so I can see the output of the last print statement?

```
print ('Hello World!')

print ('What is your name?')
myName = input()
print ('It is good to meet you, ' + myName + '!')
print ('The length of your name is: ')
print(len(myName))

print('What is your age?') #ask for their age
myAge = input ()
print ('You will be ' + string(int(myAge) + 1) + ' in a year.')

input()
```

Comment: What is `string()`?

Comment: Isn't an error message printed after te last input? What does it say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a string in Python, the method is str() not string(). So swap that out in the second last line

```
print ('You will be ' + str(int(myAge) + 1) + ' in a year.')
```